# stack too deep from callback method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have four models in Sport, Gold, Silver, and Bronze with a one to one relationship between sport and the other three. Every instance of sport must have an instance of Gold, Silver and Bronze; and three are to be created using a callback function in the Sports model. These callback function is one throwing up the error that i have been able to trace as the rails error stack produced is just a single line.
 My Code

**MODELS**

Sport

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :sportname, presence: true, 
                         uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

   has_one :gold, inverse_of: :sport, :dependent => :destroy
   has_one :silver, inverse_of: :sport, :dependent => :destroy
   has_one :bronze, inverse_of: :sport, :dependent => :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :gold
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :silver
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :bronze


   after_validation :build_default_medals, on: :create

   def build_default_medals
    self.build_gold
    self.build_silver
    self.build_bronze
  end
end
```

Gold

```
class Gold < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :sport    #, inverse_of: :gold
  validates_associated :sport, presence: true

  belongs_to :team, inverse_of: :golds, counter_cache: true 
  validates_associated :team,  :if => :create, allow_nil: true  

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sport
end
```

Silver

```
class Silver < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :sport   #, inverse_of: :silver   
  validates_associated :sport, presence: true

  belongs_to :team, inverse_of: :silvers, counter_cache: true 
  validates_associated :team, :if => :create, allow_nil: true    

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sport
end
```

Bronze

```
class Bronze < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sport   #, inverse_of: :bronze
  validates_associated :sport, presence: true

  belongs_to :team, inverse_of: :bronzes, counter_cache: true 
  validates_associated :team,  :if => :create, allow_nil: true 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sport
 end
```

The callback `after_validation :build_default_medals, on: :create` is where the error is, producing this in  my log

```
 Started POST "/admin/sports" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-14 14:52:22 -0400
 Processing by Admin::SportsController#create as HTML
 Parameters:{"utf8"=>"√",authenticity_token"=>"jss1O4bSJd3hcqxuSpu/KAxaowB7d
g5pLZw55oGDf1M=", "sport"=>{"sportname"=>"boxing"}, "commit"=>"Create Sport"}
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1       LIMIT 1  (0.0ms)  BEGIN
Sport Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `sports`  WHERE `sports`.`sportname` = 'boxing' LIMIT 1
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `sports` (`created_at`, `sportname`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-07-14 18:52:22', 'boxing', '2016-07-14 18:52:22')
SQL (15.1ms)  UPDATE `sports` SET `created_at` = '2016-07-14 18:52:22', `id` = 13, `sportname` = 'boxing', `updated_at` = '2016-07-14 18:52:22' WHERE `sports`.`id` = 13
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `golds` (`created_at`, `sport_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-07-14 18:52:22', 13, '2016-07-14 18:52:22')
SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE `sports` SET `created_at` = '2016-07-14 18:52:22', `id` =13, `sportname` = 'boxing', `updated_at` = '2016-07-14 18:52:22' WHERE `sports`.`id` = 13
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `silvers` (`created_at`, `sport_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-07-14 18:52:22', 13, '2016-07-14 18:52:22')
SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE `sports` SET `created_at` = '2016-07-14 18:52:22', `id` =13, `sportname` = 'boxing', `updated_at` = '2016-07-14 18:52:22' WHERE `sports`.`id` = 13
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `bronzes` (`created_at`, `sport_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-07-14 18:52:22', 13, '2016-07-14 18:52:22')  (72.2ms)  
ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 213ms

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:79


Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (7.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (145.1ms)
```

I am curious as to why the callback triggers update after inserting and what exactly is triggering the `ROLLBACK` and infinite loop for `Stack Level Too Deep`. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Using `after_create :build_default_medals` in place of `after_validation :build_default_medals, on: :creation` produces

```
  Started POST "/admin/sports" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-14 16:19:24 -0400
  Processing by Admin::SportsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√","authenticity_token"=>"3LrwB6+nD9PJ9EwxEgIGhN3rVHP3UPLOHUz9MXWRJ4Y=", "sport"=>{"sportname"=>"dancing"}, "commit"=>"Create Sport"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  Sport Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `sports`  WHERE `sports`.`sportname` = 'dancing' LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `sports` (`created_at`, `sportname`,`updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-07-14 20:19:24', 'dancing', '2016-07-14 20:19:24') 
 Gold Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  `golds`.* FROM `golds`  WHERE `golds`.`sport_id` =8 LIMIT 1
 Silver Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `silvers`.* FROM `silvers`  WHERE `silvers`.`sport_id` = 8 LIMIT 1
 Bronze Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `bronzes`.* FROM `bronzes`  WHERE `bronzes`.`sport_id` = 8 LIMIT 1
 (45.5ms)  COMMIT
```

**EDIT FOR `undefined method 'create' for #<Gold:0x63bf820>`**

```
def build_default_medals
  #Gold.create(sport: self, team: nil)
  #Silver.create(sport: self, team: nil)
  #Bronze.create(sport: self, team: nil)
  self.create_gold(team: nil)
  self.create_silver(team: nil)
  self.create_bronze(team: nil)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
after_validation :build_default_medals, on: :create
```

with

```
after_create :build_default_medals
```

You are trying to build associated models while sport is still a new record and not a persisted one. `validates_associated :sport, presence: true` causes a circular dependency and will give error.

I reproduced and tested with this change. It will work fine.

For saved object, use self.create_gold instead of self.build_gold, like this

```
  def build_default_medals
    self.create_gold
    self.create_silver
    self.create_bronze
  end
```

Also remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for :sport` from Gold, Silver and Bronze model. Refer - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7809

Comment: that was what i did initially but all it did and does in this instance is load the models instead of inserting into the database. And thanks for pointing out where the circular dependency is been triggered.

Comment: That can be handled by using create_gold instead of build_gold which returns saved objects, instead of just instantiated ones. However that led to finding another circular dependency in the code. I will add that an edit.

Comment: yh, but i get a weird error `undefined method 'create' for #<Gold:0x63bf820>` using create_gold, which i don't understand as it should be an added function from one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Yes, it is an added function and it is working fine on my app where I reproduced your code. Please check for minor mistakes that you might have overlooked or paste your latest edited code.